# How to reorder a two factor bar plot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I have a problem...

I can't solve this, simple and tricky, problem. I have a Barplot which were build under ggplot2 in an descending order due to several conditions (A-D). However, I can't modify the factor inside the conditions, Any help?

```
    ggplot(data, aes(x = reorder (Treatment, -mean), y=mean, fill = Rootstock)) +
  geom_col(aes(x=reorder(Treatment, -mean), y=mean), stat = 'identity', position = position_dodge(width = 0.60),width = 0.5, colour="black") +
  geom_errorbar(aes(x=reorder(Treatment, -mean), ymin = mean - se, ymax = mean + se),                            
                width = 0.1,
                position = position_dodge(0.60))
```

I don't upload the full code because it isn't worth it. If you can help me with a function to reorder the variable, I will appreciate it so much...
[image: model plot which you can see the descending orders of the conditions. However, as you can see, the ROOTSTOCK are not in descending order inside the conditions.]

Comment: In what order do you want to arrange the `Rootstock` values? Do you want them to be descending for each `Treatment` or another order? I think it'd be confusing to descend them for each treatment, as it is convention to maintain the order over all bundles of bars.

Comment: I want to put ROOTSTOCK factor in descending order for each treatment, from bigger mean bars to lowest ones. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the order of rootstock elements manually using `forcats::fct_relevel`. Alternatively use `forcats::fct_reorder()` to order by another variable.
Here's a toy example, nominally based on your plot, in the absence of a reproducible question.

```r
set.seed(101)
df1 <- data.frame(stress = rep(letters[1:4], each = 4),
                  rstock = rep(LETTERS[1:4], 4),
                  y = runif(16))

library(ggplot2)
library(forcats)

ggplot(df1, aes(stress, y)) +
  geom_col(aes(fill = fct_relevel(rstock, c("C", "A", "B", "D"))),
           colour = "black", 
           position = position_dodge2(),
           width = 0.6) +
  scale_fill_grey()+
  labs(fill = "Rootstock")+
  theme_classic()
```

[image]

```r
ggplot(df1, aes(stress, y)) +
  geom_col(aes(fill = fct_reorder(rstock, y)),
           colour = "black", 
           position = position_dodge2(),
           width = 0.6) +
  scale_fill_grey()+
  labs(fill = "Rootstock")+
  theme_classic()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-09-13 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>